# Size dimensions between parent / child

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Using Javascript, I am trying to fill up a container with div blocks which are of a 1% height and 1% width. Using a loop I created 100 of these and appended them to a container which I have centered in the middle of my page. However, the divs are not filling up the container. Why is this?

HTML - 100% height;
100% width;

body - 100% height;
100% width;

container - 50% height, 50% width;

Javascript Loop - to make 100 divs at 1% height 1% width. These are appended to the container. Aren't they supposed to fill up 1% height and 1% width of the container dimensions??

Result: only partially fills up container.  Code is listed below.

```js
const body = document.querySelector('#body');

body.setAttribute('style', 'position: relative; height:100%; width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background-Color: blue');

let container = document.querySelector('#container');
container.setAttribute(`style`, `position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0`);
container.setAttribute(`style`, ` height: 50%; width: 50%; 
display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; align-content: center; flex-wrap: wrap`)

body.appendChild(container);

console.log(container);



let gridCells = function(){
    for (i= 0; i < 100; i++){
        divCells = document.createElement('div');
        divCells.setAttribute(`style`, `height: 1%; width: 1%; background-Color: red; 
        border: 1px solid black; margin: 0; padding: 0;`);
        container.appendChild(divCells);

    }
}

gridCells()
```

```css
html,
body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
   </head>
   <body id="body">
      <div id="container">
      </div>
      <script src="etch.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want to see. Do you want the whole window to be filled with cells? If so you’d need 100 cells across, and 100 cells down. So you’d need 10000 cells in total if that was the case.

Comment: Isn't 1% height and 1% width of the container to equal only 100 cells?

Comment: "These are appended to the container. Aren't they supposed to fill up 1% height and 1% width of the container dimensions??"

Comment: If you put 100 cells of height 1% and width 1% next to each other, that would make a line across the screen that is 1% of the height, but 100% of the width. Vice versa if you put the cells on top of each other. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am not putting them right on top of each other. I am using flexbox and using flex-wrap to put them onto the next row when needed. In CSS it was my understanding that when the child clement sets a dimensions size, it sizes it off of the parent elements dimensions. 

So, what I am confused about is why my divs are not taking up 1% height and 1% width of its parent element (the container).

Comment: Yes. When you append each cell, they are being placed into the `container` div, after the last cell. Each one of these cells takes up 1% of the height of the container, and 1% of the width of the container. 1% * 1% = 0.01%. So each cell fills 0.01% of the container’s area. Therefore 100 of these cells fills 1% of the container’s area in total.

Comment: If you set the width of each cell to 100%, but keep the height as 1%, then the 100 cells will fill the container. Or you could make the height 100%, but keep the width 1%.

Comment: Ah, ok that makes sense. I was looking at at the parent / child relationship wrong. Thank you :)

Comment: I tried 100% with and 1% height, it is overspilling now on the top and the bottom.

Comment: When I run your code snippet and inspect the tiny red boxes, they do have a width of 1% of the parent's width and a height of 1% of the parent's height, _plus_ 2px each direction because of the border.  If you want that border size to be part of the height and width, you also need to set `box-sizing: border-box` on each of the `div` children.